getting ngx-virtual-scroller cannot read properties of undefined (reading overflox-x)
I'm using @iharbeck/ngx-virtual-scroller in my Angular 17 application for virtual scroll.
When using jasmine or jest for testing I'm getting this error message:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'overflow-x')
      at _VirtualScrollerComponent.set parentScroll [as parentScroll] (node_modules/@iharbeck/ngx-virtual-scroller/fesm2022/iharbeck-ngx-virtual-scroller.mjs:163:63)
      at applyValueToInputField (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4035:29)
      at Object.ngOnChangesSetInput [as setInput] (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4113:5)
      at writeToDirectiveInput (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11093:17)
      at setInputsForProperty (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12391:9)
      at elementPropertyInternal (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11692:9)
      at ɵɵproperty (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:21289:9)
      at OnrQueueTableComponent_Conditional_1_Conditional_0_Template (ng:/OnrQueueTableComponent.js:319:83)
      at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11268:9)
      at refreshView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12791:13)
      at detectChangesInView$1 (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13015:9)
      at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12978:5)
      at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12935:13)
      at refreshView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12815:9)
      at detectChangesInView$1 (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13015:9)
      at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12978:5)
      at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12935:13)
      at refreshView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12815:9)
      at detectChangesInView$1 (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13015:9)
      at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12978:5)
      at detectChangesInComponent (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12967:5)
      at detectChangesInChildComponents (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13028:9)
      at refreshView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12841:13)
      at detectChangesInView$1 (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13015:9)
      at detectChangesInViewWhileDirty (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12732:5)
      at detectChangesInternal (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12714:9)
      at ViewRef$1.detectChanges (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13310:9)
      at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:352:36
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:416:32)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:2176:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:415:38)
      at Object.onInvoke (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14882:33)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:415:38)
      at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
      at NgZone.run (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14733:28)
      at PseudoApplicationComponentFixture.detectChanges (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:351:22)

My code in my html file is:
@if(data){
  <virtual-scroller
   #scroll
   [items]="data"
   [parentScroll]="scroll.window"
  >
    .......
  </virtual-scroller>
}

And in my test file I'm importing the VirtualScrollerModule:
Imported VirtualScrollerModule and did not work. I was wondering if there  is a provider like FlatpickDefaults?
